# How can I estimate causality or the causal effect between any two variables using any statistical techniques in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy, statistics

I am new to the idea of causal inference or causality in statistic and in Python.

I have a dataframe `test` which looks as follows:

```
x   y
0   0.03    315.98
1   -0.03   316.91
2   0.06    317.64
3   0.03    318.45
4   0.05    318.99
... ... ...
58  0.92    406.76
59  0.84    408.72
60  0.97    411.66
61  1.01    414.24
62  0.84    416.45
```

`test.to_dict()` is given as:

```
{'x': {0: 0.03,
  1: -0.03,
  2: 0.06,
  3: 0.03,
  4: 0.05,
  5: -0.2,
  6: -0.11,
  7: -0.06,
  8: -0.02,
  9: -0.08,
  10: 0.05,
  11: 0.02,
  12: -0.08,
  13: 0.01,
  14: 0.16,
  15: -0.07,
  16: -0.01,
  17: -0.1,
  18: 0.18,
  19: 0.07,
  20: 0.16,
  21: 0.26,
  22: 0.32,
  23: 0.14,
  24: 0.31,
  25: 0.16,
  26: 0.12,
  27: 0.18,
  28: 0.32,
  29: 0.39,
  30: 0.27,
  31: 0.45,
  32: 0.4,
  33: 0.22,
  34: 0.23,
  35: 0.31,
  36: 0.44,
  37: 0.33,
  38: 0.46,
  39: 0.61,
  40: 0.38,
  41: 0.39,
  42: 0.53,
  43: 0.62,
  44: 0.62,
  45: 0.53,
  46: 0.67,
  47: 0.63,
  48: 0.66,
  49: 0.54,
  50: 0.65,
  51: 0.72,
  52: 0.61,
  53: 0.64,
  54: 0.67,
  55: 0.74,
  56: 0.89,
  57: 1.01,
  58: 0.92,
  59: 0.84,
  60: 0.97,
  61: 1.01,
  62: 0.84},
 'y': {0: 315.98,
  1: 316.91,
  2: 317.64,
  3: 318.45,
  4: 318.99,
  5: 319.62,
  6: 320.04,
  7: 321.37,
  8: 322.18,
  9: 323.05,
  10: 324.62,
  11: 325.68,
  12: 326.32,
  13: 327.46,
  14: 329.68,
  15: 330.19,
  16: 331.12,
  17: 332.03,
  18: 333.84,
  19: 335.41,
  20: 336.84,
  21: 338.76,
  22: 340.12,
  23: 341.48,
  24: 343.15,
  25: 344.85,
  26: 346.35,
  27: 347.61,
  28: 349.31,
  29: 351.69,
  30: 353.2,
  31: 354.45,
  32: 355.7,
  33: 356.54,
  34: 357.21,
  35: 358.96,
  36: 360.97,
  37: 362.74,
  38: 363.88,
  39: 366.84,
  40: 368.54,
  41: 369.71,
  42: 371.32,
  43: 373.45,
  44: 375.98,
  45: 377.7,
  46: 379.98,
  47: 382.09,
  48: 384.02,
  49: 385.83,
  50: 387.64,
  51: 390.1,
  52: 391.85,
  53: 394.06,
  54: 396.74,
  55: 398.81,
  56: 401.01,
  57: 404.41,
  58: 406.76,
  59: 408.72,
  60: 411.66,
  61: 414.24,
  62: 416.45}}
```

There are two variables in this dataframe `x` and `y`. x is the independent variable, and y is the dependent variable.

I can calculate the correlation between two using:

```
test.corr()
```

It returned:

```
x   y
x   1.000000    0.961354
y   0.961354    1.000000
```

This means, that the correlation between `x` and `y` is 96%. However, this does not show the causal relationship between the two variables.

How can I show statistically in Python that `x` causes `y` and show the effect by certain value?

Comment: this seems like a statistics theory question and not a programming question. maybe a better q for [stats.se]? though I imagine you'd have to provide a lot more information, and show that you've attempted to research the question yourself.

Comment: Your question is answered here: [How to find Causality in data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/319678/354591)

Comment: Thank you both! I found quite satisying [response](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/585569/how-can-i-estimate-causality-or-the-causal-effect-between-any-two-variables-usin) to this question in Cross Validated.

Answer (score 3):

Correlation is the number that can always be calculated from your data - there simply is a mathematical formula for it.

Causation, on the other hand, is knowledge about the real influence that exactly `x` has on `y`. For example, some other variable `z` may be the reason why both `x` and `y` change. `x` and `y` are correlated then. But if `x` changes doesn't mean that `y` will also change. Maybe `x` has a different reason to change that will not change `y` at all. This means `x` does not cause `y`.

Values may be correlated, but `x` may not cause on `y`, and there is no way to tell that just from the plain numbers.

There are plenty of examples online of the difference between "correlation" and "causation".

Answer (score 1):

If you know that either `X --> Y` or `X <-- Y`, and you want to know in which direction the edge is oriented, (pairwise) functional causal models are the way to go. You have to make certain assumptions or hypotheses for the resulting edge to be accurate (for example, you will assume that there are no hidden confounders).
One popular and efficient algorithm is LiNGAM (Linear Non-Gaussian Acyclic Model), which presumes that the linear function that links a variable to its parents is linear, and that the noise is additive and non-Gaussian

It's very easy to use, here is the Python library : https://pypi.org/project/lingam/

And the associated project (and papers) : [LiNGAM project](https://sites.google.com/view/sshimizu06/lingam)

For more information don't hesitate to watch Brady Neal's videos on Causality, and read Peters' book on Elements of Causal Inference.